# How to access internal hard drive from Ubuntu live USB?

Tags: 12.04, partitioning, live-usb

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 off my USB drive at the moment because my hard drive has no OS and won't allow Windows 7 to install on my internal hard drive.

Here's the low down though:

I was trying to install Windows 7 on my laptop and kept getting an error which forced me to open **DiskPart** up. I had two partitions 60GB and 220GB. All my stuff was saved on my 220GB hard drive and I wanted to install my OS on the 60GB hard drive, but I cleaned `disk 0` on DiskPart and now its all unallocated space with no partitions.

I'm hoping it didn't format the drive seeing as the clean was done in a split second. So I have no OS and I booted Ubuntu 12.04 and I'm now trying to access the internal hard drive but it won't show up in the terminal when I type `df -h`.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: In your Ubuntu 12.04 live, there will be an application called 'gparted'. Try accessing your hard drive with that.

Answer (score 1):

When you say you "cleaned `disk 0`" I'm really hoping that doesn't mean you deleted the partition table from disk 0. If that is the case, do not panic as there are ways of getting it back. *BUT DON'T TOUCH ANYTHING*. This is now a data recovery issue so the less you touch the drive the more data you will get back.

Newer versions of `gparted` have a tool to recover hard drive partitions but I still recommend dedicated tools to do that. Before you do anything however, you should clarify the current situation by booting into your USB, running gparted, and either posting a screen shot of that drive or listing exactly what partitions exist and their sizes / formats.